# PfSense VPN L2TP woes with Windows clients

Tags: vpn, pfsense, l2tp

I am using PfSense 2.3.2, an open source firewall running on FreeBSD 10.3, to provide VPNs for Windows 7 to 10 customers. I am running a pilot of the project with 200 users.

Everyone is (was) happy with the project, however, whilst there are no issues accessing internal resources in our intranet, there are complaints about not being able to open some Internet sites, like ted.com.

What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspected fragmented packet issues, and indeed, that was the problem.

After setting to on the option "IP Do-Not-Fragment compatibility" in System->Advanced->Firewall&Nat, the sites opened.

As it states in the option menu:

> Clear invalid DF bits instead of dropping the packets This allows for
>   communications with hosts that generate fragmented packets with the
>   don't fragment (DF) bit set. Linux NFS is known to do this. This will
>   cause the filter to not drop such packets but instead clear the don't
>   fragment bit.

After the fact I also found a relevant link [Unable to Access Some Websites](https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Unable_to_Access_Some_Websites)

> 9) Check Clear invalid DF bits instead of dropping the packets on
>   System > Advanced, Firewall/NAT tab.
>   10) Check Disable Firewall Scrub
>   on System > Advanced, Firewall/NAT tab.